# Cordova `barcodeScanner` return result to controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have an application written in `cordova` using `angular.js`.

In angular controller I call scan method from factory which is supposed to scan QR code and return result to controller.

Code below manages to start scanning plugin but does not return result back to controller.

What is the best approach here?

Thank you :-)

```
app.controller("LoggerController", ["$scope", "$location", qrReaderFactory", "$window", function ($scope, $location, qrReaderFactory, $window) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        qrReaderFactory.scan("logger").then(function (result) {
            $window.alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Functionality: " + functionality + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
    },
        function (error) {                
            $window.alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    );
});             

}]);  

app.factory("qrReaderFactory", ["$http", "$q", "$window", function ($http, $q, $window) {
    function scan(functionality) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function (result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            },
            function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);

            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake.

It actually works fine.

The problem was in line `"Functionality: " + functionality + "\n" +` where 'functionality' is not assigned.